# lost session after putting DB in single user mode

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have same problem as here: [SQL2005 Stuck in Single Mode User](https://serverfault.com/questions/285232/sql2005-stuck-in-single-mode-user)

Only difference, I am using SQL Server 2008. Tried everything, nothing works. When I run my

```
ALTER DATABASE [CS_10.1] SET MULTI_USER
```

or

```
ALTER DATABASE [CS_10.1] SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

after killing the connection I get the following message:

> Msg 1205, Level 13, State 68, Line 1 Transaction (Process ID 56) was
>   deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen
>   as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction. Msg 5069, Level 16,
>   State 1, Line 1 ALTER DATABASE statement failed.

A new sleeping connection to the single user database is immediately recreated after killing.

Also `SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY 10;` doesn't help.

What else can I do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work again. In my case following helped:

```
EXEC sp_who
KILL spid_taken_from_sp_who;

SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY 10;
ALTER DATABASE [db_name] SET MULTI_USER WITH NO_WAIT
```